# Basis for vector space of functions from integers to reals subject to averaging condition.

Tags: linear-algebra, algebra-precalculus, vector-spaces

Consider the space of all functions from the integers to the reals subject to the following condition. The value of a function in this space at $n$ where $n$ is any integer is the average of the integer after it and the one before it, i.e.$$f(n) = {{f(n + 1) + f(n - 1)}\over2} \text{ for all }n\text{ in } \mathbb{Z}.$$**Question.** What is a basis of the space of these functions on the integers?

Here are some of my thoughts on this question. If I had something like $f(3)$ equal to "blah" and $f(5)$ equal to "blabbity", all the rest of the values of $f$ would be fixed as a result of my condition. So "blah" and "blabbity" determine the rest of the values of this particular $f$. But here I'm stuck. Some help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's a good observation that if you know the values of $f(n)$ and $f(n+1)$ for some particular $n$, then the values of $f$ everywhere else are determined. Intuitively, this means that the space should be two-dimensional. In order to show that it is, write down two basis vectors, and then show that an arbitrary vector can be written as a linear combination of them.

There are two "obvious" vectors: the constant function $c(n) = 1$, and the identity function $i(n) = n$. You need to show that given an arbitrary $f$ in the subspace, there are constants $a$ and $b$ such that $f = ac + bi$. Here are two hints to get you started:

1. If $f$ satisfies $f(0) = 0$, you should be able to find that $f = a i$ for some $a \in \mathbb{R}$. (Prove this by induction.)
2. If $f$ does not satisfy $f(0) = 0$, you should be able to subtract a multiple of $c$ so that it does.